# Calculate the median value along specified axis for Eigen matrix

Tags: sorting, vector, eigen

Assume I have an eigen matrix of MxN, what would be the idiomatic way to get the median value alone one axis, (e.g., column wise)?

It seems to me there is no shortcut except converting each column back to a vector and then do sort and find the median value...

Comment: Is it ok to modify the columns? I don't think there is an efficient method which does not re-arrange the input (except for small `M`). Instead of sorting you should use `std::nth_element`.

Comment: sounds std::nth_element is the best/easiest way then,..